my subscriptions are ready to submit state what should i do next to test in Testflight
1- In App Store Connect under this app in the Subscriptions section, I have have created a Subscription Group with a single subscription.
2- The status of the subscription is "Ready to Submit" and at the top of the page for that subscription group I see the message "Your first subscription must be submitted with a new app version. Create your subscription, then select it from the app’s In-App Purchases and Subscriptions section on the version page before submitting the version to App Review."
